# Using lex to detect floating point numbers

Tags: c, floating-point, lex

I am trying to use lex to detect a floating point number.
The following code with input +4.23e-21
gives output

{+4.23}e-21

1

I want it to print

{+4.23e-21}

1

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>

int N_count = 0;
%}

Sign [+-]

Num [0-9]

Expo [eE]{Sign}?{Num}+

F {Sign}?({Num}*\.{Num}+)(Expo)?
%%
{F} {printf("Float = {%s}\n", yytext); N_count++;}

%%

int main()
{

    yyin = fopen("test.txt", "r");
    yylex();
    printf("%d\n", N_count);
    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `({Expo})` instead of `(Expo)` when specifying F.
I also recommend `Sign "+"|"-"` to avoid the non-terminated character range [x-y] in `Sign [+-]`.

Comment: `[+-]` and `[-+]` work in any even moderately posix-like regex system including every lex derivative I know of, because `-` must be treated as a regular character at the beginning and end of a character class.

Comment: @rici Fair enough. But it's a bit of an esoteric rule, whereas "double quotes suppress meta characters" is plain and simple. :-)

Comment: ... but won't work outside of the idiosyncratic flex environment. Backslashes introduce another obscure rule (basic or extended?) so the "put - at the beginning or end and put ] at the beginning" rule has some charm :-)